# Add 3D objects to the same scene in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, animation

I've just created a bunch of 3D objects with material settings, positions and animations that I like, using Photoshop (CC 2015).

If I play the animation with a 3D object layer selected that particular object animates fine,  but whenever I render the animation to a video nothing moves at all.

Within Photoshop, all the other objects apart from the selected one also do not animate when I play my animation from the timeline.

I suspect that this is due to all my objects being on separate (3D) layers, and therefore also being in different scenes.

**Is there anyway I could add all my objects to the same scene, without merging them as 3D layers?**

Merging them would probably work, but will destroy the animations, material settings, positions etc. It seems incredibly weird that there is no way to add an 3D object to another scene without merging. Merging would be an option if there was a way to retain all my work.